# How to remove repeating letters (consecutive) from string using JS (with regex)

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to remove consecutive letters that repeat inside a string. For example:

```
`amoebba` has to become `amoeba`
`aggolli` has to become `agoli`
`zzhhhhjjj` has to become `zhj`
```

Do you have any idea how I can do that using regex with Javascript or PHP? Actually most regex will work with any language, so if it works with JS it will probably work with PHP.

NOTE: one I alternative that I found would be to hardcode every letter in the regex something like `replace(new RegExp("(a{2,}|b{2,}|c{2,}...)","$1")` but this regex would become huge because I will have to also include latin chars like ç, á, à, ã...

Thank you.

Comment: in case you'd like to research it  yourself,  the search terms are "capturing group" and "backreference".

Comment: Try: `.replace(/(\S)\1+/g, '$1')`

Comment: One way is to repeatedly run something like replace `([a-z])\1+` with `\1` until no more changes are made.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL! I didnt know how to search it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following regular expression work? `/(.)\1+/g`

```
return inputString.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1');
```